# Any way to get an accurate ST_MinimumBoundingCircle calculation on a geography?

Tags: postgis, sqlgeography

`ST_MinimumBoundingCircle` accepts the `geometry` type, i.e. planar geometry. Is there any way to get the minimum bounding circle of a `geography` collection using PostGIS? That is, the minimum bounding circle of a collection of features *on the sphere*. Simply converting a geography to a geometry and the resulting bounding circle back to geography does not create an accurate result. This guy (via https://observablehq.com/@fil/spherical-smallest-circle-problem) seems to have it worked out in JavaScript by

> Going forward (to the stereographic plane), we compute the circumcenter of three projected points on each circle. Going backward, we use d3-geo-voronoi to retrieve the enclosing circle’s center.

Is there any built-in way to do this on PostGIS or achieve the same result using equivalent functions?